# Logback log to main file and clients in a separate directory

Tags: java, logback

I have a Java server application for which I log all the general data to server.log and each individual client to its own hostname.log file.  I want to put the hostname.log files in a different directory that server.log ideally in some organized fashion since there are thousands of hostname.log files.

This is the config I'm using now:

```
<appender name="SiftAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>descriminatorid</key>
        <defaultValue>server</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${descriminatorid}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${cmb.log.dir}/${descriminatorid}.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <!-- daily rollover -->
                <fileNamePattern>${cmb.log.dir}/archive/${descriminatorid}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
                <!-- keep ${maxbackupindex} days' worth of history capped at ${maxfilesize} total size -->
                <maxHistory>${cmb.log.maxbackupindex}</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>${cmb.log.maxfilesize}</totalSizeCap>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

This config logs everything to $cmb.log.dir.  What I'd like is something like this:

```
Server logs: $cmb.log.dir/server.log
Client logs: $cmb.log.dir/client/${descriminatorid}.log
```

Or even better would be:

```
Client logs: $cmb.log.dir/client/${firstLetter}/${descriminatorid}.log
```

where ${firstLetter} is the first letter of $descriminitorid.  That way the logs would be distributed in a more scalable hierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Instead of creating potentially an unbounded number of files it might be easier to add the client id to the log messages in a structured format and just run a simple filter on the log file.

Comment: I've tried the single log file approach and even with client id markers it's very difficult especially when dealing with customers.  For example, if I need a log file from a customer it's much easy to tell him "send me server.log and hostname.log" which will be much smaller than sending a huge single server.log file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was very simple.  Since I am generating ${descriminatorid} in my java code I simple included the directory structure i wanted in that value.  So instead of "descriminatorid" being "hostname" it's now "client/firstletter/hostname".

I was definitely trying to overthink this one.